# Problem in ScrollView scrolling?

Tags: android, scrollview

I am using a ScrollView in my layout and in the onCreate method I have used scrollTo(0,50) method, so initially when my layout appears the scrollview should be scrolled to position (0,50).
But it doesn't seem to work.

My Code is as Follows

```
ScrollView scroll;
Button btn;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    scroll.scrollTo(0,50);
}
```

I am not getting where is the problem please help

My XML Code for ScrollView is ..

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_height="200dip" >
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                    android:layout_height="30dip" android:text="ROWS 1" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                    android:layout_height="30dip" android:text="ROWS 2" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                    android:layout_height="30dip" android:text="ROWS 3" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                    android:layout_height="30dip" android:text="ROWS 4"  />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                    android:layout_height="30dip" android:text="ROWS 5" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                    android:layout_height="30dip" android:text="ROWS 6" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                    android:layout_height="30dip" android:text="ROWS 7" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                    android:layout_height="30dip" android:text="ROWS 8" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                    android:layout_height="30dip" android:text="ROWS 9" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                    android:layout_height="30dip" android:text="ROWS 10" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tabler"
                    android:layout_height="30dip" android:text="ROWS 11" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: show ur scrollview xml code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try this

```
//scroll.scrollTo(0,50);

btn.postDelayed(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //scroll.smoothScrollBy(0,50);              
        scroll.scrollTo(0,50);
    }
}, 500);
```

even better

```
btn.post(new Runnable() {           
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //scroll.smoothScrollBy(0,50);              
        scroll.scrollTo(0,50);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sam It is a great Answer I can use it in my app but it appears scrolling is occurring initially & that I dont want.Still if it is possible to directly go to the position (0,50) without the appearance of scrolling.

Comment: @AB1209: i thought you would like the animation. but then, i have update my response.

Comment: Thanks Sam It is what I want. You are a true genius ...
But I am wondering why does not scrollTo(0,50) work directly ?

Comment: thats because after onCreate.. events like onResume would fire. and scrollView will only render (draw) way later. for you code to run (in UI thread) you need to post it in the queue, this  these operation are over. Check out Activity Life Cycle.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpfull & Knowledgable